# How to convert minutes to hours in an Jupyter Notebook code?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

For an example I am trying to convert 330 minutes into hours in a notebook expression. It should return the number of hours and the remaining as minutes.

It should return the number of hours and the remaining as minutes.

Thanks in advance.

I am using Skills Network Labs framework with Pyolite as the kernel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I posted an answer but I'm not sure how Jupyter or Pyolite is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo and floor division;

```
minutes = 330 % 60
hours = 330 // 60
```

There's a neater way with `divmod`;

```
hours, minutes = divmod(330, 60)
```